# Merging a list of maps into a single map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-stream

I'm trying to merge a list of Map into a single one:

```
List<Map<String, List<Long>>> dataSet;
Map<String, Set<Long>> uniqueSets = dataset.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collector.of(
            HashSet<Long>::new,
            ...,
            ...
        )
    ));
```

The idea is that `uniqueSet` should hold a list of unique IDs (Longs) within each collection (identified by a String). But I'm not sure about the `...` parts.

As for the requested example (in JSON):

Input:

```
[
    {
        "Collection1": [1, 2, 3, 3],
        "Collection2": [2, 3]
    },
    {
        "Collection1": [3, 4],
        "Collection3": [1, 2]
    }
]
```

Output:

```
{
    "Collection1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "Collection2": [2, 3],
    "Collection3": [1, 2]
}
```

Comment: If these are supposed to be _unique,_ don't you want a Set?

Comment: What if two maps have the same key with a different value ? in two separate runs you might get two different results (meaning, it's not consistent).

Comment: @alfasin I'm not sure what you mean. But if two maps have the same key, the result should have that key once with a merged list of their lists. I mean that's the whole idea.

Comment: does the `dataSet` list of maps already have the lists within the map with unique ids or there might be duplicate ids in a given list for a given entry of map contained in `dataSet` list?

Comment: @VikasPrasad To be safe, let's consider the initial lists are not composed of unique ids.

Comment: can you provide a sample input and output of what you expect? Specially regarding the duplicate values?

Comment: I wrote "the same key with a different value " if you choose to read one part of the sentence and ignore the rest, then you're right - it makes no sense... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question, if given these two maps:

```
{Mike=[5, 6], Jack=[1, 2, 3]}
{Fred=[7, 8], Jack=[4, 5]}
```

You want to combine them like this:

```
{Mike=[5, 6], Fred=[7, 8], Jack=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Here you go:

```
Map<String, List<Long>> uniqueSets = dataset.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collector.of(
            ArrayList<Long>::new,
            (list, item) -> list.addAll(item.getValue()),
            (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; })
    ));
```

That is:

- You got the supplier right: create a new `ArrayList` to accumulate values
- The second piece is the accumulator: something that takes a container (the list) and an item, and adds the item to the container. Note that the items are `Map.Entry` instances.
- The final piece is a the combiner, to merge two containers populated by accumulators into one

Comment: I am not sure on the part of the question where it demands *list of unique ids*. If the `Jack` in the first map is having `[1, 1, 2, 3]`, does the final `Jack` needs to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` or `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: A question: shouldn't all the pieces be left untouched (immutable)? By that, I mean `list` and `left` which are modified in your code.

Comment: @Mehran Only lists created during the collect will be mutated, the original map content will be untouched. The purpose of the accumulator is mutating something. As for the combiner, the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#combiner--) clearly states that it's ok to fold one side into the other.

Comment: @janos hey what would be the way to do the same in java7 where collector groupingBy is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
    Map<String, List<Long>> uniqueSets = dataset.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collector.of(
                            ArrayList<Long>::new,
                            (x, y) -> { x.addAll(y.getValue()); },
                            (x, y) -> {
                                List<Long> r = new ArrayList<>(x);
                                r.addAll(y);
                                return r;
                            }
                    )
            ));
```

**EDIT:**

Other approach is

```
    Map<String, List<Long>> uniqueSets = dataset.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> new Pair(e.getKey(), v)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Pair::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            Pair::getValue,
                            Collectors.toList()
                    ))
            );
```

But it requires pair class (you can find similar class in many libraries)

```
class Pair {
    final String key;
    final Long value;

    public Pair(String key, Long value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Map<String, Set<Long>> uniqueSets = new HashMap<>();
dataset.forEach(map -> map.forEach((string, list) -> {
    if (uniqueSets.get(string) != null){
        list.forEach(id -> uniqueSets.get(string).add(id));
    }else{
        uniqueSets.put(string, new HashSet<>(list));
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> r =
    dataSet.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Long>(e.getKey(), v)))
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println(dataSet);
System.out.println(r);
```

result:

```
[{Collection1=[1, 2, 3, 3], Collection2=[2, 3]}, {Collection1=[3, 4], Collection3=[1, 2]}]
{Collection1=[1, 2, 3, 4], Collection3=[1, 2], Collection2=[2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you specifically asked for a stream-based solution with a custom collector, here's a way:

```
List<Map<String, List<Long>>> dataSet;
Map<String, Set<Long>> uniqueSets = dataset.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collector.of(
            HashSet<Long>::new,
            (set, e) -> set.addAll(e.getValue()),
            (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; })));
```

---

However, I think there's a much better solution without streams:

```
Map<String, Set<Long>> uniqueSets = new HashMap<>();

dataSet.forEach(map -> 
    map.forEach((k, v) -> uniqueSets.merge(
        k, 
        new HashSet<>(v), 
        (o, n) -> { o.addAll(n); return o; })));
```

This iterates over the list of maps, and for each map, it iterates over its entries, so that for each key/value pair of each map, the value is transformed into a `HashSet` that is mapped to the key in the `uniqueSets` map. This is accomplished by means of the `Map.merge` method, which creates the entry if it wasn't present in the map, or merges the new value with the old value if there was already a key for that value. For this merging, I'm using `Set.addAll`.